# DjangoでWebアプリを作りたい。

Tags: django

Djangで次のようなアプリを作りたいです。入力フォームから、名前や価格を送信。データベース(Djangoのデフォルト)に保存。保存したデータベースをスプレッドシートに書き出す。
以上の機能を持たせたいのですが、どのようなファイル構成やコードが考えられますか？
少しでも、道筋、手順を示していただけるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 1):

djangoをインストール、設定する手順です。
とりあえず、クリーンな状態でdjangoが起動するところまで、記載しました。
（質問内容のほぼすべてが記載された書籍がいろいろあり、お勧めです。）

[前提条件]
WindowsのWSL2 + Ubuntuを利用

1)djangoのインストール、環境設定

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install django
```

2)djangoのプロジェクト、アプリケーションの作成

```
django-admin startproject test_project
cd test_project
python3 manage.py startapp test_app
```

3)アプリケーションの設定
[test_project/test_project/settngs.py]をエディタで開き[INSTALLED_APPS]配列の末尾に、

```
'test_app.apps.TestAppConfig',を追加する。
```

4)データベースの初期化

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
python3 manage.py createsuperuser
→UsernameとPasswordを入力すること
```

5.djangoテスト実行

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

ブラウザよりhttp://localhost:8000/へアクセス
および
ブラウザよりhttp://localhost:8000/adminへアクセス
作成したユーザーでログインできればOK
ctrl + Cでdjangoを終了できる。

Answer (score 1):

・フォルダ構成
フォルダ構成は、
　test_proj/test_proj ← プロジェクトフォルダ
　test_proj/test_app ← アプリケーションフォルダ
プロジェクトの中に、複数のアプリケーション(サブサイト)が包含される関係になります。

アプリケーションフォルダ内の、ファイル構成は、
　・urls.py
　　リクエストの振り分け（projectフォルダ内にもあるので注意）を行います。
　　リクエストがきたら、どのviewを利用して、どのHTMLテンプレートを利用するか、指定します。
　・views.py
　　サーバーサイドの処理を記載します。
　　モデルクラスの参照更新(データベースアクセス)、HTMLへ表示する項目を作成します。
　・models.py
　　データベースのテーブルをORMしたクラス
　・templateフォルダ
　　html、htmlテンプレートを記載します。

・データベース(Djangoのデフォルト)に保存
モデルクラスを作成するとよいです。
小規模であれば、一般的に[test_proj/test_app/models.py]に記載します。

```
################################################################################
from django.db import models
CATEGORY = (('business', 'ビジネス'), ('life', '生活'), ('other', 'その他'))

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        choices = CATEGORY,
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

[test_proj/test_app/admin.py]ファイルに、

```
admin.site.register(Book)
```

と追記することで、デフォルトの管理者サイトからデータを確認することができます。

・入力フォームから、名前や価格を送信。
入力フォームなどのhtmlは、[test_proj/test_app/template/]フォルダに保存します。
どのようなリクエストがきたら、どのhtmlファイルを利用するかは、[test_proj/test_app/urls.py]に記載します。
サーバーサイドでの処理は、[test_proj/test_app/views.py]に記載します。

・保存したデータベースをスプレッドシートに書き出す。
スプレッドシートに書き出す処理は、分かりません。
他の方の回答を期待してください。